# Multiple texture outputs on a different fbo

Tags: opengl, glsl

i'm trying to calculate data using textures, and reading from Ping fbo while writing to Pong fbo.

an explanation picture of what i'm trying to achieve:
[image: fbo pingponging]

here's my call code:

```
glUseProgram(TexturedShader);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, PongFbo);
        //  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(n0->PingVao);

        Write(ping, n0, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nN, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nE, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nW, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nS, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nSE, TexturedShader);
        Write(ping, nSW, TexturedShader);

        WriteOut();

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


void Write(bool ping, Tabela* N, GLuint Shader)
{
        if (ping)
        {
            glActiveTexture(static_cast<GLenum>(static_cast<int>(GL_TEXTURE0)+N->MyNr()));
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, N->PingTexture);
        }
        else
        {
            glActiveTexture(static_cast<GLenum>(static_cast<int>(GL_TEXTURE0)+N->MyNr()));
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, N->PongTexture);
        }

        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Shader, N->MyName().c_str()), N->MyNr());

        if (glGetUniformLocation(Shader, N->MyName().c_str()) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "not bound sucessfully " << Shader << " " << N->MyNr() << " " << N->MyName().c_str() << std::endl;
        }

}

void WriteOut()
{

    GLenum DrawBuffers[7] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT5, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT6 };
    glDrawBuffers(7, DrawBuffers);

}
```

For some reason it works without setting layouts on shaders, but only for the first buffer? I also get no errors or missing uniforms.

and my shader:

```
#version 450 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
layout(location=0) out vec4 n0out;
layout(location=1) out vec4 nNnSnEout;
layout(location=2) out vec4 nWnNEnNWout;
layout(location=3) out vec4 nSEnSWout;

layout(location=4) out vec4 densityout;
layout(location=5) out vec4 velxvelyout;

layout(location=6) out vec4 speed2out;


layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D n0;
layout(binding=1) uniform sampler2D nNnSnE;
layout(binding=2) uniform sampler2D nWnNEnNW;
layout(binding=3) uniform sampler2D nSEnSW;

layout(binding=4) uniform sampler2D density;
layout(binding=5) uniform sampler2D velxvely;

layout(binding=6) uniform sampler2D speed2;

//uniform vec2 barrier;

float viskoznost = 0.02f;
float omega = 1 / (3 * viskoznost + 0.5); //Relaksacijski cas
float stiri9ne = 4.0 / 9;
float ena9na = 1.0 / 9;
float ena36na = 1.0 / 36;


float nN0 = 0;
float nN = 0;
float nS = 0;
float nE = 0;
float nW = 0;
float nNE = 0;
float nNW = 0;
float nSE = 0;
float nSW = 0;

float ndensity = 0;
float nvelx = 0;
float nvely = 0;

float nspeed2 = 0;

void Trk(){

            if (!(gl_FragCoord.x > 300 &&  gl_FragCoord.x < 301 && gl_FragCoord.y >400 && gl_FragCoord.y < 600))
            {

                float n = nN0 + nN + nS + nE + nW + nNW + nNE + nSW + nSE;
                ndensity = n; // macroscopic density may be needed for plotting
                float vx, vy;
                float ena9naN = ena9na * n;
                float ena36naN = ena36na * n;
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    vx = (nE + nNE + nSE - nW - nNW - nSW) / n;
                }


                else vx = 0;
                nvelx = vx; // may be needed for plotting
                if (n > 0){
                    vy = (nN + nNE + nNW - nS - nSE - nSW) / n;
                }
                else vy = 0;
                nvely= vy; //needed for plotting
                float vx3 = 3 * vx;
                float vy3 = 3 * vy;
                float vx2 = vx * vx;
                float vy2 = vy * vy;
                float vxvy2 = 2 * vx * vy;
                float v2 = vx2 + vy2;
                nspeed2 = v2;       // may be needed for plotting
                float v215 = 1.5 * v2;

                nN0 += omega * (stiri9ne * n * (1 - v215) - nN0);
                nE += omega * (ena9naN * (1 + vx3 + 4.5*vx2 - v215) - nE);
                nW += omega * (ena9naN * (1 - vx3 + 4.5*vx2 - v215) - nW);
                nN += omega * (ena9naN * (1 + vy3 + 4.5*vy2 - v215) - nN);
                nS += omega * (ena9naN * (1 - vy3 + 4.5*vy2 - v215) - nS);
                nNE += omega * (ena36naN * (1 + vx3 + vy3 + 4.5*(v2 + vxvy2) - v215) - nNE);
                nNW += omega * (ena36naN * (1 - vx3 + vy3 + 4.5*(v2 - vxvy2) - v215) - nNW);
                nSE += omega * (ena36naN * (1 + vx3 - vy3 + 4.5*(v2 - vxvy2) - v215) - nSE);
                nSW += omega * (ena36naN * (1 - vx3 - vy3 + 4.5*(v2 + vxvy2) - v215) - nSW);
            }
}

void main()
{ 
nN0 = texture(n0, TexCoords).x;
nN = texture(nNnSnE, TexCoords).x;
nS = texture(nNnSnE, TexCoords).y;
nE = texture(nNnSnE, TexCoords).z;
nW = texture(nWnNEnNW, TexCoords).x;
nNE = texture(nWnNEnNW, TexCoords).y;
nNW = texture(nWnNEnNW, TexCoords).z;
nSE = texture(nSEnSW, TexCoords).x;
nSW = texture(nSEnSW, TexCoords).y;

ndensity = texture(density, TexCoords).x;
nvelx = texture(velxvely, TexCoords).x;
nvely = texture(velxvely, TexCoords).y;

nspeed2 = texture(speed2, TexCoords).x;
    Trk();
      n0out.x = nN0;
      nNnSnEout.xyz = vec3(nN,nS,nE);
      nWnNEnNWout.xyz = vec3(nW,nNE,nNW);
      nSEnSWout.xy = vec2(nSE,nSW);

      densityout.x = ndensity;
      velxvelyout.xy = vec2(nvelx, nvely);

      speed2out.x = nspeed2;
}
```

edit: fixed the code

Comment: It's not obvious to what this question actually refers.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Also don't pastebin half the code.

Comment: The code is not working, sorry for not being specific. I can't read any of the textures.

Comment: Just done a bit of debugging, apparently none of the unforms are actually getting bound...

Comment: This looks like it shouldn't work at all. As best I can tell what you are doing here is trying to write to the same textures you are sampling from. That requires a memory barrier of some sort to work correctly. NV has texture barriers, but even they are not adequate and the only surefire way to do this would be with imageLoad / imageStore and memoryBarrier.

Comment: added an explantion pic, to try and explain what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

After days, I have finally fixed the problem, it appeared that i had to use layouts(bindings) to bind the input textures, and then use glDrawBuffers to tell it which texture should be written on to the current FBO.
The read FBO didn't matter, i only had to call texture names (those called with glGenTextures), and didn't have to specify the fbo at all.
I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: This answer is rather... confusing. Could you clarify what it means to `call a texture`?

Comment: i had to "call" the textures by their handles (names), type of GLuint, set by glGenTextures. While the output was set by glDrawBuffers

Comment: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturename); glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Shader, texturename), 0);